# How to pass data from NSMutableArray to PowerPlot

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, charts, nsmutablearray, plot

I have two `NSMutableArrays` one is filled with `NSNumber` values the other with `NSDate` values.
Does anyone can help passing this values to `PowerPlot` to draw a linechart where the `NSDate` values should be the x axis

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
WSPlotAxis *axis = (WSPlotAxis *)[self.aView lastPlot].view;
[self.aView generateControllerWithData:[WSData dataWithValues:aTimeValues] plotClass:[WSPlotData class] frame:self.aView.frame];
```